# Planning a table to form mapper

Tags: forms, tables, data-mapping

I have a html table which i am using to display data from a database. The table is paginated and i have a form that allows a user to edit the data on row click.

I am wondering which of the two approaches will be more usable.

The first is the table being on top and the form being beneath or the form being on top and the table being beneath.

[image]

Comment: Hi Le Qs. If you provide a picture of what you currently have, it will make finding an answer to your question much easier.

Comment: @Tory Updated the question with picture. Thats the arrangement i have currently. The table on top and the form at the bottom.

Comment: If you want to know which is more usable, you should perform some usability testing with your target users and measuring what they do. Asking for opinions on Stack Exchange is not usability testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Master > detail

This falls into a pattern called **master-detail view**, with the table being the **master**, the form being the **detail**.

The detail should follow the master, so the form should follow the table in the visual flow.

## Neither is optimal

If I'm perfectly honest, neither solution is UX-optimised. Depending on the height of the table, the form may live below the fold. Also, if interaction with the table is sequential (users sometimes have to edit rows one after the other), having the form at either ends means having to jump across the visual space.

Think proximity. Ideally the form is displayed in a way that makes it clear that it refers to a particular table row.

I had a similar problem with an accounting system. Possible solutions included:

1. Modal
2. Inline-editing
3. Popup
4. Row-collapse (AKA accordion table)

I won't get into the pros and cons of each, but after analysis, deliberation and corridor user-testing we've opted for the later one (row-collapse). Something like this:

[image: A screenshot showing a table, with a + or - icon next to each row allowing the row to expand vertically.]

Although it worked great on that system, on other systems the row-collapse was problematic, so when we could we used a classical master-detail view (master on the left, detail on the right).